# My query is only showing the first line of data when I order by asc, but it works normally when I filter by desc

Tags: google-sheets

[image: As you can see in column K]

When I filter is by desc, it shows all of the data. Is there something I missing?

Comment: Would everything be the sam, just add sort in front?

Comment: NaziA It seemed to work, however, the amount of rows returned don't equal my limit....closer though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY(dependentdata1, 
 "where X is not null 
  order by X asc 
  limit "&K2, 1)
```

Comment: It seems to give me a parse error, do I still use `select *`?

Comment: if you want to output all column there is no need to use `select *`

Comment: what says the error? can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ji3Q02uOyrDXyrl7LcghWLcLjz-CeSUgSCU7QD0BVEk/edit#gid=978677639

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: how do you make it public?

Comment: I think my company put restrictions in sadly

Comment: I was able to get it, and it works great thank you! again!

Answer (score 1):

Let's say this is your function:

`=query(E2:G5, "select * order by E asc")`

Your query looks like this and should work:

`=query(E2:G5, "select * order by E desc")`

So I am not sure what is wrong with yours.

However, you can trying wrapping it up with `SORT` and use the `desc` one since it works on your case.

`=sort(query(E2:G5, "select * order by E desc"), 1, FALSE)`

#### Sort Parameters:

- 1st parameter = data
- 2nd parameter = column to sort
- 3rd parameter = TRUE (ascending), FALSE (descending)

#### Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks Ill try that! May I ask what the 1 and False represent for the Sort function? Ill mark it as a correct answer since it seems to fix it for me

Comment: Hi @BrandonSmith, The `1` is what column is being sorted on. I'm sorting based on the first column so `1` is used. `FALSE` means descending, while `TRUE` is ascending.

Comment: Whats interesting, is i think this is a google sheets glitch. I tried reverting to a version from this morning where it was working normally and ordering by ascending, now all of those versions are doing this also

Comment: @BrandonSmith. Hmm, it seems that this hack will fix your issues with that glitch. I too have encountered earlier a wrong sorting by `query` thus recommended this approach.

Comment: @BrandonSmith, If you want to avoid the glitch, maybe try only querying via `query` and sorting using `sort`. Since it seems `sort` is more reliable than `query` and `order by`. Updating my answer.

Comment: Are you able to set limits with Sort?

Comment: @BrandonSmith, I forgot that there was a limit on your query. Nevermind my statement earlier. it will not bode well.

Answer (score 0):

My query is utilizing data from an `=importdata` function. So when the query updates, it seems to glitch out and only show the 1st row of data. I was able to revert it to a previous date where I was not having this issue and it did it when it updated. I'm sure there are some if functions I can use to resolve it, however, a `=sortn` function was able to allow me to place limits on what I wanted to sort and return `=SORTN(U2:W, K2, TRUE)`